# ./sonar.sh start on ubuntu giving not starting sonar server

Tags: ubuntu, sonarqube

I have downloaded sonar 3.5.1 from [sonar](http://dist.sonar.codehaus.org/sonar-3.5.1.zip) using wget "http://dist.sonar.codehaus.org/sonar-3.5.1.zip" command. Then I unziped using `unzip sonar-3.5.1.zip` command. But when I tried to start sonar using "sudo ./sonar.sh start", I got the error:

```
 .../sonar-3.5.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./wrapper:Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Failed to start sonar.
```

May I know the reason by anyone.

edited:
output of uname -a,

```
Linux ocrfrt 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:32:08 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add details about your environment? Most notably the version of your Linux distro ("uname -a"). For your information, I'm using SonarQube on Ubuntu without any problem so there's no reason why you wan't manage to make it work.

Comment: I have edited the question with required info

Comment: Well, I'm really surprised, this should work w/o any problem... I don't know how you can debug this, as the issue is on the wrapper side and this wrapper has always been working correctly :-/

Comment: oh...actually this is my remote box. I created mysql DB for sonar and edited sonar properties file also. I am able to start sonar on my local machine but unable to start on remote machine.

Comment: I am sorry my remote system is of 32bit machine and i was trying with linux-x86-64 sonar.sh to start...My problem is fixed

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are running a 32 bit machine.

Just edit /etc/systemd/system/**sonar.service** file and change linux-x86-**64** for linux-x86-**32**

```
ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-**32**/sonar.sh start

ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-**32**/sonar.sh stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this command:

```
sh sonar.sh start
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced same issue and later identified that installer provided in bin/ directory was used other than the OS actual architecture.

First do check the OS architecture (x86-32 or else) and do use correct installer as per the OS architecture.