# Sonarqube wrapper syntax error with 64 and 32 bits sh call

Tags: ubuntu, sonarqube

I've install SonaQube on a ubuntu Xenial server with this tutorial: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-sonarqube-on-ubuntu-16-04

all installations (postgreSQL, java, sonarqube, apache2, etc.) work fine but I always get an syntax error when I try to start sonar with:

```
/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
```

I get:

```
/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/./wrapper: 1: /opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/./wrapper: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

And I get exactly the same error using :

```
/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-32/sonar.sh start
```

so it seems to be a different problem than that post :
[./sonar.sh start on ubuntu giving not starting sonar server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735862/sonar-sh-start-on-ubuntu-giving-not-starting-sonar-server)

my uname -a :

```
Linux scw-2a7881-sonarqube 4.4.95-mainline-rev1 #1 SMP Fri Oct 27 08:56:55 UTC 2017 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

has someone got the same problem ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your kernel information (aarch64), you are trying to start SonarQube on a ARM64 architecture and the wrapper in linux directory is not compatible with this architecture (the wrapper binaries are for x86 or amd64 architecture).

Comment: thank you for you quick answer! so there is no solution for me?

Comment: I would say that if you are not running a production server you can try to start SonarQube with the following command :

  java -jar lib/sonar-application-6.6.jar \
  -Dsonar.log.console=true \
  -Dsonar.jdbc.username="$SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME" \
  -Dsonar.jdbc.password="$SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD" \
  -Dsonar.jdbc.url="$SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL"

Comment: Ok thank very much. Well, this will become the production server, it's fast enough for me to switch to a 64bits x86 server and reinstall, I'll do this instead.

Comment: I do think it's really better (than trying to start it without the wrapper).

Comment: Where can i find the binary for ARM64?